# Getting flex items to stretch and vertically center content at the same time?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a row of flex items and I would like the content of the each item with the row to be vertically centered and I also would like the item to stretch from the top of the row to the bottom such that the background color of the item shows from top to bottom.  Is this possible.  Right now my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="u-flex u-height-4rem u-flex-align-items-center">
  <div class="u-width-25rem u-padding-left-3rem u-padding-right-3rem">u-background-color-gray-{{weight}}</div>
  <div class="u-background-color-gray-{{weight}} u-width-100"></div>
</div>
```

If I add `u-flex-align-items-stretch` (Same thing as `align-items: stretch`) the items stretch from the top of the row to the bottom, but now the content is no longer vertically centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the parent `flex` and that will put the children in columns in the `row`, `stretch`ed by default. Then you can make the children `flex`, too, and use `align-items: center` to center their contents. Depending on what's actually in the content in each column, you might want to wrap the content in an element like a `div` so that the `div` is centered and the content inside of it is treated normally.

```css
.u-flex, .u-flex > div {
display: flex;
}

.u-flex > div {
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-flex u-height-4rem u-flex-align-items-center">
  <div class="u-width-25rem u-padding-left-3rem u-padding-right-3rem" style="background:red">u-background-color-gray-{{weight}}<br>foo<br>bar<br>foo<br>bar</div>
  <div class="u-background-color-gray-{{weight}} u-width-100" style="background:grey">asdf<br>asdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdf<br>asdfasdf<br>asdf<br>asdf</div>
</div>
```